# File path error while adding localization files to project

Tags: ios, localization, localizable.strings

I am working an application where i have to localize my app. Previously I was able to select any country(language) while localizing, but now when I try to add any localization file, it gives me popup saying,

> The file path /Users/...../hi.lproj/LaunchScreen.strings is invalid. 
>   The expected prefix is /Users/..../Base.lproj.

Also, when I add any file to localizaton, it does create a folder in the directory, but .strings file is not shown in Base.lproj folder.

I did tried different solutions provided on the internet for the same problem, but none of them worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternate to the above issue. I created a new strings file from the file menu in xcode.

After creating that file, click on that file and click on 'Localize' button in File inspector tab.

After that, i tried to add new localization files from target to my app. It did gave me a file path error, but ignore it. You will be able to localize your string.